# Compute $\lim\limits_{x \to 0^{+}} \lfloor \frac{1}{\ln x} \rfloor$

Tags: limits

Compute $\lim\limits_{x \to 0^{+}} \lfloor \frac{1}{\ln x} \rfloor$.
I tried to use the fact that $\frac{1}{\ln x} - 1\le \lfloor \frac{1}{\ln x} \rfloor\le \frac{1}{\ln x} $, but this is inconclusive.

Comment: You can show that if $0<x<\frac{1}{e}$ then  $\lfloor \frac{1}{\ln x} \rfloor=-1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from the fact that

$${1\over\ln x}-1\lt\left\lfloor1\over\ln x\right\rfloor\le{1\over\ln x}$$

we can add the fact that for $0\lt x\lt1/e$ we have $\ln x\lt-1$, so that $-1\lt1/\ln x\lt0$, from which we obtain

$$-2\lt{1\over\ln x}-1\lt\left\lfloor1\over\ln x\right\rfloor\le{1\over\ln x}\lt0$$

Since $\lfloor1/\ln x\rfloor$ is an integer, this implies

$$\left\lfloor1\over\ln x\right\rfloor=-1$$

for all $0\lt x\lt1/e$, hence

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\left\lfloor1\over\ln x\right\rfloor=-1$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=e^z$; then $z\to -\infty$ as $x\to 0^+$

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\lfloor 1/\ln x\rfloor=\lim_{z\to -\infty}\lfloor 1/z\rfloor=\lim_{z'=1/z\to 0^-}\lfloor z'\rfloor=-1$$